# Show combination of affine functions and logs has at most one zero

Tags: real-analysis, logarithms

For $x>0$, let

$$
f(x)=(x+2){\sf log}(x)-(x+1){\sf log}(x+1)
$$

Can anybody show that the equation $f(x)=0(x > 0)$ has at most one
solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We compute
$$
f'(x) = 1 + 2/x + \log x - 1 - \log (x+1) = 2/x - \log (1 + 1/x).
$$
We want to show that this is positive. Putting $y = 1/x$, we just need to show $2y > \log (1+ y)$ for all positive y.

But these two functions are equal when $y = 0$ and the result is then clear by the concavity of the logarithm.